# Вычислить процент из двух timestamp

Tags: c#, php, c++

Есть 2 timestamp:

```
timeStart = 1426373964
timeEnd   = 1426719564
```

Если текущее время `time() > timeStart`, нужно высчитать, сколько уже прошло времени до `timeEnd` в процентах.

Рассуждал так:

```
100% это 1426719564
```

`time()` - это некоторый **x%** от **1426719564**, чтобы его найти, я делаю:

```
$new = (time() * 100) / timeEnd
```

Но что-то не то...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю сделать это так:

- 100% = (timeEnd - timeStart)
- Х% = (time() - timeStart)

Откуда Х вычисляется как: Х = (100 * (time() - timeStart))/(timeEnd - timeStart)

Comment: Спасибо - попробую этот вариант. Кстати, почему-то условие не срабатывает `if(time() > $timestart)`

Comment: Сравнивается `time() > 1426371984`

Comment: Ну это уж я не могу ответить. Выведите обе переменные в дебаг, да посмотрите.

Comment: Только, наверное, чуть наоборот:

     timeEnd - timeStart

и

     time() - timeStart

а также неплохо бы убедиться, что 

     timeStart < time() < timeEnd

выполняется.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, не заметил ошибку.

Answer (score 2):

Я так и не понял, на каком языке надо, в тэгах и C++, и C#... Видимо, надо сам принцип. Ну вот на C#, например:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        DateTime startTime = unixEpoch.AddSeconds(1426373964);
        double seconds = (double)(1426719564 - 1426373964);
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0:P}", (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds / seconds);
        }
        while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
    }
}
```